# How to troubleshoot or resolve of hardware acceleration of Intel i945 disabled on upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04?

Tags: drivers, xorg, 18.04, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I've experienced an issue where hardware acceleration of my Intel i945 mobile display chip set has been disabled during an in-place upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04.

Unfortunately none of the existing filed bugs I've found seem related to my problem, or at least the fixes don't work for me.

Any ideas of where I could start looking for error messages related to this?  (eg X.org logs etc etc) or remedies I could try?

FWIW, hardware acceleration under a live-cd boot of 18.04 seems to work fine and all resolutions are available and it was also working perfectly under 17.10.

I also had to add "nomodeset" to grub boot commands, otherwise machine would hang during boot process

Barring any options, the simplest fix may be a re-install but that seems drastic for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Intel i915 video.

Switching from **gdm3** to **lightdm** fixed the problem.

In `terminal`...

- `sudo apt-get update` # update the software database
- `sudo apt-get install lightdm liblightdm-gobject-1-0` # install lightdm
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` # set lightdm as the DM

Choose `lightdm` and then `OK`

- `reboot` # reboot the machine (*remove **nomodeset** if you still have it enabled*)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work so I went ahead with the full reinstall.   Interestingly enough, it worked on the initial reinstall.  However, once I installed updates (sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade) it went right back to not working again.   Something in the updates released since the initial release are messing things up.